# Examples when wavefunction is changing but probability density is constant?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability, time-evolution

What are examples of wavefunction that changes with time but the square of wavefunction is constant?

Comment: You would get this if only the phase changes.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a homework question...

Answer (score 1):

Energy eigenstates have this property. If a state is an energy eigenstate, then the time-dependent Schrödinger equation is

$$i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = H \psi $$
$$= E \psi$$

which is solved by

$$\psi(x,t) = \psi(x)e^{-itE/\hbar}$$

where $\psi(x)$ solves the time-independent Schrödinger equation,

$$H \psi = E \psi$$